# Grab Managers from AD

Tags: powershell

I'm currently getting a list of managers in AD from

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "DirectReports -like '*'" -Properties *
```

Whats the easiest way to scan this against the entire AD domain to see if they are a manager?

Not working code:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *
Foreach ($User in $Users) {
If (Get-AdUser -Identity $User -Filter "DirectReports -like '*' -eq $True") 
{Write-Host "$User is a Manager"} Else {Write-Host "$User is NOT a Manager"} 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Definitely NOT like you're currently doing.  Do managers have a DirectReports attribute unlike other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties directReports | ForEach-Object {
  $isManager = ($_.directReports | Measure-Object).Count -gt 0
  $_ | Select-Object name,
    @{Name = "Manager"; Expression = {$isManager}}
}
```

Comment: @curtcab Depending on the size of your business, querying every user through active directory twice is going to be extremely slow. (although it appears he edited it to remove the second query)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 thank you, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - I noticed it and corrected the answer about the same time you posted your comment (which was right on).